# Mac M1 chip issues with rosetta, “attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1”

Tags: macos-big-sur, apple-m1, rosetta

I recently got a Mac with the apple M1 chip and I am having numerous problems running libraries and applications.

One such example is numpy. To provide context, I installed Python 3.9 and pip3 and then decided to use pip to install numpy. To test if Python 3.9 and numpy have been properly installed, I type in terminal `python3`. I next try importing numpy using the statement `import numpy`

I then get the error

```
/var/db/oah/e089a6709d38c1a085254c76a7cb592fcceddb3f234a4aa318bb4ec25fe40d27/a37f39d2b061393d7731233ae89d90cd87c97f4edeeb46a78ad791/_multiarray_umath.cpython-39-darwin.so.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1
zsh: trace trap  python3
```

I have the **exact same error** when trying to open other applications (eg. SonicWall Mobile Connect) from the apple app store. If anyone has any insight to how to resolve this rosetta error it would be very much appreciated.

Cheers!

Answer (score 38, accepted):

One of the following will fix the issue IMHO.

1. Restart Mac OS.
2. Upgrade OS (will restart after the upgrade)
3. Upgrade Docker, Upgrade OS, restart.

I had the same issue on Apple Silicon (M1Pro) running on Mac OS Monterey (12.0). I installed Rosetta2 and problem persisted. I deleted and reinstalled Docker but that did not fix the problem. After reading other answers on this question, I realized that for some people, OS upgrade was solving the problem.

Comment: Number 1 fixes it for me with Monterey; usually a problem with After Effects and not Docker but I've no doubt this will come up there too as I use both

Comment: A restart also fixed it for me. I checked my uptime before I rebooted, and it started happening at around 30 days uptime (last reboot was the 12.0.1 update, it started around 3 days ago). I guess the more stable the OS becomes the more likely this is to happen 

Comment: macOS 12.0.1 Monterey: A restart fixed it for me

Comment: Updating macOS also solved it for me. I was getting a "Kernel Restarting: The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically" message from Jupyter that was hiding this issue.

Comment: Restarting helped me

Comment: restarting worked but the error came back few hours later.

Comment: As a temp fix, you can remove your `bin` directory everytime you run, eg: `rm -rf ./bin && dotnet run`

Comment: First tried docker upgrade; didn't work. Restarting worked for me. On Ventura 13.3.1 with M1 mac

Comment: Hi there.  This solved the problem for my team who use M1 or M2 macs.  Is there any information on why a restart works and seems to solve memory allocation issues?

Answer (score 12):

FWIW - Same behaviour on macOS Monterey 12.6.1.
Simple restart solved the problem. Nothing else was required.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 10):

What worked for me:

Verify that Rosetta is installed on your Mac. Rosetta should be installed automatically when you try to run an Intel-based application on an Apple Silicon Mac. If it's not installed, you can manually install Rosetta using the following command:

```
softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Comment: Fixed it for me too. Was having multiple problems with random apps just not working anymore. Seems like somehow one of the ventura updates must have broken rosetta for me. Thanks!

Comment: I have MacOS ventura and after updating to Visual studio for mac 17.6.5 I was Facing the issue..
softwareupdate --install-rosetta this helped me to resolve the issue

Comment: I was running into issues with Docker Desktop on my M1 MBP and this resolved the issue. The error I was getting was:

npx expo run:android
Error: rosetta error: failed to open elf at /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

Answer (score 5):

This was happening to me a lot. Restarting fixed the issue but it would happen again soon after. Restarting so often would be a pain.

This answer on another question helped me fix the issue without having to restart:

```
dotnet clean
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/74197116/1266153

Answer (score 3):

The same problem has occurred for me as well, but with Big Sur 11.5 update as another comment has pointed out before me.
What I did to fix the error was to update from Big Sur 11.5 to Big Sur 11.6.
From there the issue resolved itself for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2):

I am using `M1 Mac Monterey 12.3.1`, I had to switch over to using Docker Compose V2.  After I did this and restarted the Docker for Mac engine client app, the CLI started working again (though the buttons in the app still gave errors).

Good luck!

[image: Preference Docker Compose v2]

Comment: In my case, I had to disable Docker Compose V2 for this to work on my M1 running Ventura 13.4. Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out this was an Apple software issue. (I believe it was update 11.4, but I am not 100% sure.) After doing the software update the rosetta issue disappeared and all of the software that was having problems with it earlier now function properly.

Comment: I had the same issue, upgrading from macOS 11.4 to 11.5 fixed the issue for me as well.

Comment: Already I upgraded my macOS to 11.5, Now I am having the same error for Eclipse app
`rosetta error: /var/db/oah/22326....etc/eclipse./eclipse.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 3
Trace/BPT trap: 5`
Can anyone know the solution pls comment here

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue after upgrading to `Monterey 12.3.1`,
tried restarting MacOS but that didn't help.

Later figured out that I was not able to build java applications using Java 8 but
Java 11 applications were running fine.

Issue got resolved after installing java 11 from https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java11-mac

Answer (score 0):

I just upgraded my OS to macOS Ventura. Then suddenly certain commands in terminal stopped working.

All I had to do was:

1. Quit Terminal
2. Disable 'Open Using Rosetta'
3. Open Terminal again.

Answer (score -1):

I just had the same problem and I realized that I had the AMD64 binary.

`file /Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql /Applications/SnowSQL.app/Contents/MacOS/snowsql: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`

I used Homebrew to install, i.e.

```
brew install --cask snowflake-snowsql
```

Comment: Question is not related to SnowSQL.