# Mac M1 chip machine, Mac OS BigSur Version 11.5.1 having problem with eclipse app. Its not opening after restarting machine

Tags: eclipse, macos, apple-m1, rosetta

I Installed eclipse on my new mac m1 chip machine, It was working fine until I restart my machine. After restart the machine, the eclipse app is not opening also no error is shown in the display..
I am trying to open the app in terminal I am getting the following error

`rosetta error: /var/db/oah/223263137464320_223263137464320/27e2cf6e452a44ee1a3ccc20e0409d562f65d18f27dd9ff3ebd552b78e52a4e3/eclipse.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 3 Trace/BPT trap: 5`

the solution giving in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68372849/8842148) is to upgrade the OS, but I already upgraded to the new OS version.
I can't find a solution anywhere, even in Apple forum sites

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue today. In my case, I'm using Anypoint Studio, which is built on top of Eclipse 4.19. After updating the OS, it worked again.

Comment: which OS version you are using now?

Comment: Hi @ArunKumar, I'm using 11.5.1

Comment: I too using 11.5.1
Installing new eclipse solved my problem :)