# Dotnet Watch Run gives me a Rosetta Error: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1 after save

Tags: docker, .net-core, apple-m1, rosetta

I'm having a problem with my .Net Core 3.1 Project. I'm using Docker for hosting the MS SQL Database (image azure-sql-edge) and I run it on a MacBook Pro M1 Max.

When starting the project with Dotnet Watch Run everything works ok but after a save in Visual Studio Dotnet Watch Run restarts and gives me an error:

rosetta error: `/var/db/oah/0cbcd548c398ac044cf47633c4e5aa068c1a0416a18ad1861a768ac56fd1d33b/68b61c75aa9514f21db1470814e91bac8c95ea1a32f4e42fc88601dc4eeac1fc/Project.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1`

And Dotnet watch gives a:

```
dotnet watch ❌ Exited with error code 133
```

Anybody has a clue what's going wrong here?

Comment: Same issue. Did you found solution?

Comment: @EmilSabitov No sorry, I still have the issue :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After updating Dotnet DSK to 3.1.425 (release date November 8th 2022) the issue was fixed.

Answer (score 5):

I am a frontend developer and I am no expert in dotnet, it just so happened that our backend is dotnet and In my case, running `dotnet clean` then running my backend again `dotnet run --project=MyProject` help me solve this issue. Hope this helps you solve your issue.

Answer (score 1):

I got same issue on M1 with .netcore 3.1
tried serval things. but didn't solved. but, yesterday my co-worker said try run `dotnet clean` and It works like magic.

since before I have to reboot my pc everytime when this error occured. and now I am happy. hope this simple command helps.

once again, just run `dotnet clean` no other flags used.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it by updating the target framework to the newest version on my machine - typing "dotnet --version" into the command line will show you the latest version you are running.
For me it was going into the .csproj file and updating the target framework within there. Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue on M1 with .Net 6.0.402. Upgrading MacOS to Ventura 13.0 (22A380) solved it for me.

Updating to latest SDK 7.0.100-rc.2 did not help here.