# Docker cannot be started or stopped from both Docker Desktop and the terminal

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to stop a container both through docker desktop and terminal , but I get thrown with the following error message:

Cannot stop Docker Compose application. Reason: Error invoking remote method 'compose-action': Error: Command failed: docker-compose-v1 --file "docker-compose.yaml" --project-name "odoo-15-usa" --project-directory "/Users/fatimah.naqib/odoo15/odoo" stop rosetta error: /var/db/oah/279293133324288_279293133324288/6a20165d5b5f6b7aedcebca858402cc97cc991baa52def27f7cca94fe77ca73c/docker-compose.aot: attachment of code signature supplement failed: 1

Comment: are you using Mac OS? came across this post where restart is one among three suggestions - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68204296/mac-m1-chip-issues-with-rosetta-attachment-of-code-signature-supplement-failed

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell based on limited info.

1. Check that you have the necessary permissions to run the docker-compose command by running ls -l in the relevant directory.
2. Check the docker-compose.yaml file for any syntax errors or incorrect settings by running docker-compose config.
3. Check that the Docker Compose application is installed and functioning correctly by running docker-compose --version.